# Magento 2 How to redirect to a custom block from a Controller

Tags: frontend, controllers, redirect-url

I have added a front phtml file followed by a Block, I need to redirect to that block from a controller.

this is the Block path, it's working fine.

```
http://mywebsite.co/schools/schoolzone_search/index/display
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $resultRedirectFactory;
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirectFactory)
{
$this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
}
public function execute()
{
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$url ="schoolzone_search/index/display";    
$url_2 = "http://mywebsite.co/schools/schoolzone_search/index/display";            
return $resultRedirect->setPath($url);
}
}
```

in Network it's showing as 200 OK, But it is not redirecting to the **Phtml Page**.
Where am doing wrong? Can I get help?. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
    class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirectFactory)
    {
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $url ="schoolzone_search/index/display";    
    $url_2 = "http://mywebsite.co/schools/schoolzone_search/index/display";            
    return $resultRedirect->setPath($url);
   $resultRedirect->setUrl('/frontname/controller/action'); //add your redirect url here or you can simply paste a page url here
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Chikku for answering. I updated code as `$resultRedirect->setPath('/schoolzone_search/index/display');` instead of  `$resultRedirect->setPath($url);` but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    
    class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $resultRedirectFactory;
        public $storeManager;
    
        public function __construct(
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        )
        {
            $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
            $this->storeManager=$storeManager;
        }
        public function execute()
        {
            //$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
             $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            //$url ="schoolzone_search/index/display";    
            //$url_2 = "http://mywebsite.co/schools/schoolzone_search/index/display";
            $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('schools/schoolzone_search/index/display', ['_current' => true]);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath($url);
        }
    }
```